# Как реализовать общую дисковую память для Ubuntu и Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hdd, dual-boot, раздел

У меня установлены параллельно Ubuntu 14.04 и Windows 7.

Ubuntu — 25 Гбайт, Windows — 234 Гбайт.

Под Ubuntu свободными остались 2 Гбайт.

**Вопрос:**
Как мне cделать общую память для Ubuntu и Windows? Заранее cпаcибо.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос? Речь про дисковую память ? Нужен общий раздел для обмена данными или что ?

Comment: никто не мешает "подмаунтить виндовый раздел" к линуксу. ntfs драйвер сейчас работает достаточно хорошо. Но как минимум чтение точно хорошо работает.

Comment: Для ubuntu лучше ext, для win - ntfs. По моему мнению лучше не совмещать, особенно если место под саму систему(т.е. на разделе с linux) заканчивается. Снимите образ, добавьте памяти на линуховый раздел и закатайте образ обратно

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня терабайтник в ntfs для торрентов используется, ос: ubuntu 12.04. До этого alt linux и opensuse. Не возникало проблем с записью никогда. Ну и с чтением всё норм (кроме ACL).

Comment: @Chubatiy не нужно снимать образ и перенакатывать. Все делается в течении получаса подручными средствами. Вначале с под винды раздел чуточку уменьшается, потом загружается лайв диск с убунтой и линукс раздел двигается и расширяется (тут пригодиться gparted, который все это сделает в графическом режиме).

**donRumata** вполне может быть. Я же этого не отрицал.

Comment: @KoVadim тем более! Вопрос только в том, где именно закончилось место(под систему или фильмы, к примеру). Возможно и просто можно не парится, а смонтировать ntfs диск и все.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать часть раздела ntfs не размеченной. Если не размеченная область будет не рядом с диском ext, то диск ntfs надо сдвинуть так чтобы не размеченная часть была возле ext раздела, после чего нужно просто расширить ext раздел.
Думаю все это можно сделать с помощью [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)

Comment: можно по подробней - про MiniTool..... это cофт только под Windows?

Comment: @Вадим Николаев, для ubuntu вы можете использовать [GParted](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/gparted), будьте осторожны так как передвигание разделов может поломать вам загрузчик, но если вы умеете его восстанавливать то проблем быть не дожно.

Comment: cпаcибо , Вы отчень помогли.Был рад получить адекватный ответ , вмеcто: "Google в помощь"

Comment: @ВадимНиколаев Интернет и существует для того чтобы каждый вопрос имел ответ!! Думаю я заслужил стрелочку вверх))